# Centering <div> in a sidebar-free area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to center this `#wrapper <div>` in the sidebar-free area on the page. With these options it is centered on the whole `<body>` and goes behind the sidebar.

```css
#wrapper /* Centers #posts <div>, but at the same time it makes #posts <div> go behind the sidebar, which I don't want to. */ {
    width: 800px;
} 
#posts {
    width: 800px;
    float: left; /* Is needed for the Masonry script. */
}
.entry /* Sets options for each post in two columns in #posts <div>. */ {
    width: 400px; /* Musthave option too. */
}
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table; /* Is needed for centering stuff inside of the sidebar. */
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'> <!-- This one is supposed to be centered in the sidebar-free area on the page. -->
        <div id='posts'>
            <!-- Here are all of the posts. -->
                <div class='entry'>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='sidebar'>
    </div>
</body>
```

What it looks like now:

[image]

What I what it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some padding to the body to compensate for the sidebar width. If you add the same amount of padding as the sidebar width the whole body will be pushed to the left. Please see the snippet.

You can also use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) to achieve this if you don't have to support

```css
/* New =================================================================== */

body {
    /* Push content of the body to the left. Use same amount as the sidebar width */
    padding-right: 250px;
    /* Remove default margin */
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {        
    /* Centers the wrapper */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Old =================================================================== */

#wrapper /* Centers #posts <div>, but at the same time it makes #posts <div> go behind the sidebar, which I don't want to. */ {
    width: 800px;
} 
#posts {
    width: 800px;
    float: left; /* Is needed for the Masonry script. */
}
.entry /* Sets options for each post in two columns in #posts <div>. */ {
    width: 400px; /* Musthave option too. */
}
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table; /* Is needed for centering stuff inside of the sidebar. */
}

/* Demo ============================================================= */

#wrapper {
    /* So you can see it in the demo */
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
}

#sidebar {
    /* So you can see it in the demo */
    height: 80px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'> <!-- This one is supposed to be centered in the sidebar-free area on the page. -->
        <div id='posts'>
            <!-- Here are all of the posts. -->
                <div class='entry'>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='sidebar'>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The easiest solution. Thank you! Like literally, I hope you feel my rays of love. <3

Answer (score 0):

Additional CSS

```
#main-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 250px;
    right: 250px;
    bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Main HTML

```
<body>
    <div id='main-content'>
        <div id='wrapper'> <!-- This one is supposed to be centered in the sidebar-free area on the page. -->
            <div id='posts'>
                <!-- Here are all of the posts. -->
                    <div class='entry'>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='sidebar'>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This additional CSS moved my posts even more to the right. :( @tbwill4321

Comment: Ahh, I thought you wanted it centered between the sidebar and the right edge of the screen.  Updated to fix it so that it centers between the left and right edges of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a http://fiddle.jshell.net/p05drxpk/1/

To start with I set the body to:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I also set percentages instead of pixels and set box-sizing so paddings will not expand elements to not fit.

Comment: Thank you! Will try this one later!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, try this:

```
#wrapper /* Centers #posts <div>, but at the same time it makes #posts <div> go behind the sidebar, which I don't want to. */ {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: 500px;
  background-color: purple;
} 
#posts {
  margin-right: calc(50% - 400px);
  width: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
  float: right; /* Is needed for the Masonry script. */
}
.entry /* Sets options for each post in two columns in #posts <div>. */ {
  width: 400px; /* Musthave option too. */
}
#sidebar {
  position: fixed; 
  background-color: red;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  display: table; /* Is needed for centering stuff inside of the sidebar. */
}
```

I used the calc() function to get the posts id in the middle. The formula used in the calc() function was basically full-width - half of the element this class was created for(the posts id) and for the wrapper id it was calc(full-width - sidebar id full-width).

Comment: Thanks! Will check this one too!